# AFNetworking.framework: No such file or directory in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I just opened my project in Xcode 8.0 and tried to build it, but the following "PBXCp Error Group" appeared:

```
error: /Users/username/Documents/XYZ/build/Debug-iphoneos/AFNetworking.framework: No such file or directory
```

My Podfile is below:

```
platform :ios, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'XYZ' do
  pod "MSSTabbedPageViewController"
  pod "SKStatefulTableViewController", "~> 0.1"
  pod "QBFlatButton"
  pod "LTNavigationBar"
  pod "KBRoundedButton"
  pod "CTCheckbox"
  pod "SKStatefulTableViewController", "~> 0.1"
  pod "SDWebImage"
  pod "TOCropViewController"
  pod "UIImageViewAligned"
  pod "AFNetworking"
  pod "MBProgressHUD"
  pod "JSONModel"
  pod "CWStatusBarNotification"
  pod "Firebase/Messaging"
  pod "MaterialControls"
  pod "Fabric"
  pod "Crashlytics"
end
```

Pod is installed and OK.

I don't know what I did, since Cocoapods seems to be in the build folder.

Comment: based one error you need to remove `pod "AFNetworking"` and update pod. once all updation done agin add `pod "AFNetworking"` in your pod file and update your pod it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had the same issue. Adding and removing AFNetworking from podfile didn't help at all. The only thing that worked for me was to remove AFNetworking.framework and add it again from correct path. The original path was pointing to wrong direction...

Answer (score 0):

change the platform :ios, '10.0' to older platform and update pod file it will work fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

try to add it properly because i had recently install all pod file in my side it working fine for me.remove your pod file and then install it.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the item "Copy only when installing" in build setting just worked for me.