# xcode afnetworking.network no such file

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking

I'm working on an iOS App.
I'm trying to archive the app and I am encoutering this :

> /Users/eenovinfogerance/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Mercato-ascjcoguyyeglqcxxlubcypqxcdm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Mercato/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications//Mercato.app/Frameworks/AFNetworking.framework: No such file or directory

I'm new in iOS, I tried to remove and add again pod 'AFNetworking', I also tried to make a pod install / update without success...

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Did you open the workspace file?

When you open the project file, xCode cannot find the pods. So you have pods installed you should open the workspace. Also when archiving the project.

Comment: Not sure to understand what you're talking about with the workspace, my pods works fine, except AFNetworking...

Comment: Hmm, have you also tried the solution given here ?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40217073/2164516

Comment: Yes but don't get the part where I'm supposed to remove AFNetworking.framework and add it from correct path, cause there is no such file at all in my folder...